# How do I access current retry attempt when using @Retryable approach

Tags: spring-boot, spring-retry

I am using annotation based approach - `@Retryable` to do retry in spring boot application.

```
@Retryable(value = {DataAccessException.class, JpaSystemException.class}, maxAttempts = Integer.MAX_VALUE, backoff = @Backoff(delay = 30000))
```

What I want to do is, everytime it retries I want to access its current retry attempt.

I tried doing this using Java Reflection -

```
Retryable retryable = mth.getAnnotation(Retryable.class);
```

But using this I am not getting the current retry attempt. It just gives the details which are been added to the `@Retryable` attribute like `value`, `maxAttempts`, `Backoff` details

Any idea on this? Help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 15):

You can't access the template, unless you wire up your own interceptor and provide it to the `@Retryable` in the `interceptor` property.

You can, however access the count within the `@Retryable` method using

```
int retry = RetrySynchronizationManager.getContext().getRetryCount();
```

Comment: very useful. Thanks

Comment: Any prerequisite for using RetrySynchronizationManager.getContext()?  In which scenarios it could be null?

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that the bean with the method is not actually advised by a retry interceptor - that would happen, for example, if there is no `@EnableRetry` on a `@Configutation` bean. Another possibility is an internal call to the method from the same class, which bypasses the proxy. If neither of those are the case, I suggest you ask a new question with code/config.