# Azure spring boot function - get current retry count

Tags: java, spring-boot, azure, azure-functions

I found we can set up retry count in azure function  using below annotation

```
@FixedDelayRetry(maxRetryCount = 3, delayInterval = "00:00:05")
```

question is how do we get current retry count? I need to copy message to failed queue after 3 unsuccessful retry, could not find any way to do that.

Issue mentioned at : https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/2595 is closed.

I could not understand final resolution? do we have any property on ExecutionContext that can be used to get current execution count?

Answer (score 0):

By using the retry listener you can be able to get the retry count

Something like this

```java
 @Retryable( value = SQLException.class, maxAttempts = 5, 
                backoff = @Backoff(delay = 100), listeners = {"retryListener"})
    void testMethod(String abc) throws SQLException{
    //some method body that could throw sql exception
    };
```

Below is the example code on printing the retry count on error

```java
@Slf4j
@Component
class RetryListener extends RetryListenerSupport {

    @Override
    public <T, E extends Throwable> void close(RetryContext context,
                                               RetryCallback<T, E> callback, Throwable throwable) {

        log.error("Unable to recover from  Exception");
        log.error("Error ", throwable);
        super.close(context, callback, throwable);
    }

    @Override
    public <T, E extends Throwable> void onError(RetryContext context, RetryCallback<T, E> callback, Throwable throwable) {
        log.error("Exception Occurred, Retry Count {} ", context.getRetryCount());
        super.onError(context, callback, throwable);
    }

    @Override
    public <T, E extends Throwable> boolean open(RetryContext context,
                                                 RetryCallback<T, E> callback) {
        log.error("Exception Occurred, Retry Session Started ");
        return super.open(context, callback);
    }
}
```

Also,

> how do we get current retry count?

To get the current retry count you need to provide `@Retryable` in  `Interceptor` property

Below is the example code.

```
int retry = RetrySynchronizationManager.getContext().getRetryCount();
```

Check the [SO1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64313342) and [SO2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53084765) for related information.

Comment: thanks for checking... however this looks for spring. I'm looking for something for msft azure function library